# Python regular expression applied to list

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have an excel file that I am trying to extract information from, specifically from the 5th column ('Summary'). Each element of 'Summary' is a string; I am trying to find the age of the person mentioned.  The age info will either be "John Smith, 23," or "John Smith, a 23-year-old". The first row of data isn't valid, so I skipped it.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am searching for 2 digits followed by either a comma or a dash, then trying to return the 2 digits.
Thanks for the help

```
import pandas as pd

mf=pd.ExcelFile(myFile)

m=mf.parse('myDataFile')

age = []
s = m['Summary']

for a in s[1:]:
    x = re.search('[0-9]{2}',a)
    y=x+1
    age.append(a[x,y])
```

Comment: Try this website to verify your regular expressions: https://regex101.com/

Comment: can you add 2-3 sample input lines and show complete expected output for that? I am not clear what you expect `y=x+1` to do

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize the regular expression returned a "match" object, not an integer.  I was able to get it to work using this:

```
s=m['Summary']
age =[]
n=re.compile('\d\d(,|-)')

for t in s:
    x= re.search(n,t)
    if x:
        b=x.group(0)
        age.append(b[:2])
    else:
        age.append("NA")
```